# Expose protected/private attributes to certain classes

Tags: php, class, scope, protected

I want to give class `B` the ability to access the `protected` attribute `x` of class `A`.
It is important to note, that I do not want to make `x` either `public` nor do I want to expose its contents via a `getter` function.
The only classes that should have access to `A->x` are `A` and `B`.

```
<?php
class A
{
    protected $x = 'some content';
}

class B
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function print_x()
    {
        print '???';
    }
}

$b = new B(new A());
$b->print_x();
```

I am looking for solutions to achieve this.

Comment: Class B extends Class A

Answer (score 2):

Class `B` will have access to class `A` protected members if class `B` extends class `A`.
A child class will have access to protected members of the parent class.  A child class can also override the methods of the parent class.

You use **inheritance(parent/child relationship)** when one class extends the feature of another class.  For example class `square` can extend class `rectangle`.  Class `square` will have all the properties and features of class `rectangle` plus its own properties and features that make it different from a `rectangle`.

You are implementing **composition** by passing in class `A` into class `B`.  Composition is used one class *uses* another class.  For example,  an `user` class may use a `database` class.

```
    class A
    {
        protected $x = 'some content';
    }

    class B
    {
        protected $a;

        public function __construct(A $a)
        {
            $this->a = $a;
        }

        public function print_x()
        {
            print '???';
        }
    }

    $b = new B(new A());
    $b->print_x();
```

Recommended readings:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29

http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2008/05/04/inheritance-vs-composition/

If you have to use reflection then you can try this:

```
class A
{
    protected $x = 'some content';
}

class B 
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function print_x()
    {
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($this->a);
        $reflectionProperty = $reflect->getProperty('x');

        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);

        print $reflectionProperty->getValue($this->a);

    }
}

$b = new B(new A());
$b->print_x();
```

Comment: `A` and `B` must not extend each other. Otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: @StefanKass: I think you want reflection.  See my edited answer.

Comment: @StefanKass: I just read your comment.  You seem to want a design pattern.  There's no such design pattern.  Because it seems that you are trying to break encapsulation which is fundamental part of OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes

Answer (score 1):

Extend class A with class B.

An alternative if you do not want to extend class A with class B is to use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Comment: The reflection approach sounds good. But I have to toggle visibility to public to achieve that and it's quite an overhead. Thanx though.